# Django 3rd party login duplicate email

Tags: django, authentication, gmail-api, google-developers-console

I set up my django application to be able to sign in with google and facebook 3rd party applications. However, whenever I already have an account that signs up with a gmail account that already exists, I get a weird signup page that looks like this:

```
Menu:
Sign In
Sign Up
Sign Up
You are about to use your Google account to login to example.com. As a final step, please complete the following form:

Username: 
testuser

An account already exists with this e-mail address. Please sign in to that account first, then connect your Google account.
E-mail (optional): 
email@test.com

Sign Up »
```

Is there a way to fix this so it can ask the user for a different email instead of breaking like this? When the user hasn't been registered before through the application, this problem does not occur.

Answer (score 0):

Simple. Make a test function that checks if the user (when attempting to Login), already exists based on email, username, or what-have-you, and return that message to the user.

For Example:

```py
def login(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        # perform some logic
        try:
            User.objects.filter(email=email).exists()
            return "User with email already exists"
        except User.objects.filter(email=email).DoesNotExist():
            return "User doesn't exist yet"
```